# drupal 6: how to write a query to insert into the content type

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

I have created a content type named history
when ever users want to opens specific page the content history should be inserted with new row.

I'm using rules but stucked with query.

I have written a simple query to insert the data it even works but the problem when I fetch the data in view it doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't good way to create content type for logs. Just create simple table with columns:
nid (node id), visited (datetime of visit), uid (user id, for guests = 0)

In your module add this:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_exit().
 */
function YOURMODULENAME_exit() {
  drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_PATH);

  if ((arg(0) == 'node') && is_numeric(arg(1)) && (!arg(2))) {
    global $user;
    $node = node_load(arg(1));
    if (in_array($node->type, array('some_content_types'))) {
      db_query('INSERT INTO {somelogtable} VALUES(%d, %d, %d)', $node->nid, time(), $user->uid);
    }
  }
}
```

And somewhere you can show listing of this nodes.
For more example. look statistics module as sayed above.

Comment: i have done this but when i create a node it doesn't show in the view may be i have to use node_save cck filds which is  bit tricky...

Comment: You should add in your module "views.api" support. Please read about it in http://views-help.doc.logrus.com/help/views/api-tables

Answer (score 0):

Can't [the Statistics module](http://drupal.org/handbook/modules/statistics) help you? "It counts how many times, and from where each of your posts is viewed".

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, seems a bit strange to use a content type for your viewing history, but I'll go with it. So you want history to have a new node created whenever a certain page is viewed, right? You're going to have to use a custom module for this.

You could write a module that implements [hook_init()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_init/6) to do something like:

```
<?php
    MODULENAME_init() {
        if (drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']) == 'the_path_alias_of_your_page') {
            // create your node here, see http://api.drupal.org/api/function/node_submit/6 for example
            // then save it using node_save($node)
        }
    }
```

Obviously that's really rough, but it'll get you started.

Are you sure you can't just use Google Analytics or the like?